# How to create dynamic URLs using routing in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, routes, url-rewriting, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I have a blog project in which I have a post-detail component but the URL is static. I want to add the post title to the URL to make it dynamic for each post. If this is possible for you then please add related code also.

Comment: Hi, i think you want to parametrize your route? Probably this tutorial can help you https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/routeparams

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.